# iOS 17 , when entering Chinese characters, the program crashes. The system is using UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, keyboard, uiwebview, ios17

iOS 17 , when entering Chinese characters, the program crashes. The system is using UIWebView.
This is my error message.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0FHw.png).

I know that Apple recommends replacing UIWebView with WKWebView, but I hope to find a faster solution to this problem.
i've noticed that in the iOS 17 environment, there is an underline when typing Chinese characters. Is this due to UIWebView not supporting the display of this underline
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: `WKWebView` has been around since iOS 8. There's no reason to keep using the very outdated `UIWebView` (which was deprecated in iOS 12). It will be much quicker to switch to `WKWebView` than to try to work around issues with an unsupported and out-of-date `UIWebView`.

Comment: I have a similar issue. Have you found a faster solution without replacing UIWebView? Thanks.